# Подскажите, нужна ли запятая после части "когда только закончилась война"?

Tags: запятые, спп

**Думать о нем сейчас куда легче, чем поначалу, когда только закончилась война и Сакура осталась совершенно одна.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думать о нем сейчас куда легче, чем поначалу, **когда только закончилась война и Сакура осталась совершенно одна.**

Запятая перед союзом И не ставится, так как он соединяет однородные придаточные времени.